# How to work with tabs in new gnome-terminal?

Tags: profile

After going Debian 8 (with Kali 2) I can no longer use my pre-defined tabs because apparently some genius decided that gnome-terminal no longer needs that kind of functionality.

I really need my tabs back so I installed a pre 3.11 version that worked with tabs and profiles like this (see below) but that caused other problems.

```
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=Titleable -t "sami" -e "byobu" --tab-with-profile=Titleable -t "root" -e "sudo -i screen -dRRS sami" --tab-with-profile=Titleable -t "samimox1" -e "ssh root@samimox1 -t screen -dRRS main"
```

Can I install older gnome-terminal side-by-side the "new and improved" version? Or is there a way to get tab profiles to work with the new one?

Answer (score 1):

gnome-terminal is now so broken it is basically a bad joke. Profiles are difficult or impossible to manage, edit or delete.

If I ignore the recent transparency issues I got mate-terminal finally working by making my old profiles more accurate. Apparently mate-terminal now employs more stricter error checking mechanism and no longer work with undefined profile names ie. --tab-with-profile=Default only works in one profile (the first one.) Your next profile must be named differently (Default2 or for instance "Servers" like in my example below) and it must reflect in the new profile custom command.

example:

```
mate-terminal --tab-with-profile=Servers -t "server1" -e "ssh root@server1.domain.com -t screen -dRRS main"
--tab-with-profile=Servers -t "server2" -e "ssh root@server2.domain.com -t screen -dRRS main"
```

By using more precise Profile definitions and custom commands in mate-terminal I can ones again get all my profiles and 100 or so Tabs in good order up and re-connected with a click of a button :)

Gotto love the **screen -dRRS main** command. This allows you to reboot and return to your previous work with one click. All your terminal tabs will be exactly like you left them before you rebooted including the previous "on screen" command history.

-Sam

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (sort of.)

```
apt install mate-terminal
```

Then just change the command to mate-terminal (+options) instead of gnome-terminal (+options).